# More than one type in @Category annotation

Tags: java, gwt, annotations, autobean

The GWT [AutoBean page](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#Categories) says:

> The @Category annotation may specify more than one category type.

The following syntax gives **Syntax error on token ",", / expected** :

```
@Category(FooCategory.class, BarCategory.class)
public interface FooBarFactory extends AutoBeanFactory { 
    ...
}
```

What is the syntax for specifying multiple category classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the parameters with `{` and `}`

```
@Category({FooCategory.class, BarCategory.class})
public interface FooBarFactory extends AutoBeanFactory { 
    ...
}
```